# Переменные перемешиваются

Tags: c

Я только недавно начал изучать C и написал код, но после какого-то момента переменные просто перемешиваются. Почему так происходит?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void save_file(char name[], int a, int b)
{
    int c = a + b;
    
    FILE *file;
    char filename[150];
    sprintf(filename, "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\result.txt");

    file = fopen(filename, "w+");
    fprintf(file, "Your name is %s;\n%d + %d = %d;", name, a, b, c);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    char name[] = "";
    char save[] = "";
    int a = rand() % 251;
    int b = rand() % 251;

    printf("Enter your name:\n> ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
    printf("Save file? (y/n)\n> ");
    scanf("%s", save);

    if (strcmp(save, "y") == 0)
    {
        save_file(name, a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какие переменные и что значит перемешиваются?

Comment: @rusgeli когда код создаёт файл то вместо имени я вижу пустое место, а переменные "a" и "b" не похожи на рандомные числа

Comment: @rusgeli не особо могу объяснить, может только у меня такая проблема? Попробуй запустить код и посмотреть на результаты

Comment: Имя вводится в массив недостаточной длинны. Переписывается чужая память, начинается хаос (на языке профессионалов - неопределённое поведение).

Comment: Ещё одно: `scanf("%s",` - зло. Никогда не используйте эту конструкцию.

Comment: Объявите `char name[100];` и вторую переменную тоже переделайте. Проблема уйдёт на время.

Comment: Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy понял, спасибо

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiyпочему вы считаете что `scanf("%s"` - зло

Comment: @SpaceResearcher, эта конструкция не контролирует число прочитанных символов. Она будет работать пока слова достаточно короткие. На длинном слове - неопределённое поведение. То есть, это бомба, которую вы не видите на тестах и которая рано или поздно взорвётся. Зло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для всех переменных выделяется фактическое место хранение и фиксированный размер выделенной памяти. Вы выделили строкам всего по одному байту. И пытаетесь что-то поверх записать.

```
char name[] = "";
char save[] = "";
scanf("%s", name);
```

Просто-так увеличится размер не может и вы записываете, портя память других переменных.

Для массивов нужно выделить память побольше и при считывания с консоли нужно указывать лимит байт, чтобы и функция `scanf` никакую память сама не испортила.

```
char name[256] = "";
char save[256] = "";
scanf("%255s", name);
```

---

II. В функции `save_file` вы не закрыли файловый буфер и файл не запишется. Нужно вызывать `fclose`.

```
fclose(file);
```